Ошибка связей sqlalchemy, в FastApi
вот мои связи моделей
это user
recipes: Mapped[list['Recipe']] = relationship('Recipe', back_populates='user')
comments: Mapped[list['Comment']] = relationship('Comment', back_populates='user')
favorites: Mapped['FavoriteItem'] = relationship('FavoriteItem', back_populates='user')

это recipe
user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
user: Mapped['User'] = relationship('User', back_populates='recipes')
comments: Mapped[list['Comment']] = relationship('Comment', back_populates='recipe')
rating: Mapped[list['Rating']] = relationship('Rating', back_populates='recipe')
favorites: Mapped[list['FavoriteItem']] = relationship('FavoriteItem', back_populates='recipe')

это comment
user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
recipe_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
user: Mapped['User'] = relationship('User', back_populates='comments')
recipe: Mapped['Recipe'] = relationship('Recipe', back_populates='comments')

это rating
recipe_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
recipe: Mapped['Recipe'] = relationship('Recipe', back_populates='rating')

и избранное
user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
product_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
user: Mapped['User'] = relationship('User', back_populates='favorites')
recipe: Mapped['Recipe'] = relationship('Recipe', back_populates='favorites')

ошибка такая
raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Recipe(recipes)], expression 'User' failed to locate a name ('User'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'src.culinary_recipes.models.recipe.Recipe'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

